# favorite icon disappears after changing section on the website

Tags: html, favicon, fullpage.js

I'm loading my favorite icon like this:

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/logoico.ico">
```

And I'm using fullpage.js. So when I click a button to go to a different section my url changes from this:

```
file://localhost/Users/mauriciosanchezduque/Documents/codeMath/index.html
```

to this:

```
file://localhost/Users/mauriciosanchezduque/Documents/codeMath/index.html#secondPage
```

and the favicon disappears. Any idea?

Comment: Strange. Have you tried giving an absolute path to your href?

Comment: maybe the problem with your directory

Comment: I tested your code and it works well..

Comment: Is your website publicly accessible so we can try it for our self? Since this is weird. Also try adding a forward slash before your favicon.ico path like so: `href="/images/logoico.ico"`

Comment: @msound I don't have it public yet

Comment: @Krimson@msound This is the link for the website it doesn't load the icon http://54.235.78.67/codeMath/index.html

Comment: @mauricioSanchez I've added my answer, I hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... according to the link you provided. When I view the source, I see

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

but your favicon is located here: `http://54.235.78.67/codeMath/images/logo.ico`

**Here your path is wrong and the filename Is also wrong. Try using this:**

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/logo.ico">
```

Comment: Gosh, for some reason that favicon.ico was something different. IT helped, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your favicon is in dir

```
file://localhost/Users/mauriciosanchezduque/Documents/codeMath/images
```

Just change href of icon to

```
file://localhost/Users/mauriciosanchezduque/Documents/codeMath/images/logoico.ico
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to keep this name `favicon.ico` and to place it in the root.
Also put these line in the head:

```
 <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Or

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

And the file `favicon.ico` must be 16x16 bits.

Note that the file must be in the root. But if your file has the `favicon.ico` you can even not write those lines above in your code

Comment: For some reason it doesn't load at all, check this out http://54.235.78.67/codeMath/index.html

Comment: I checked. Make sure the file is in the root. And I have updated my answer. For some reason I missed the ”or” and `/`.